# How to solve non-resolvable parent pom.xml error?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Maven goal fails letting us know the parent pom.xml is not resolvable. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

```
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.opencastproject:opencast-engage-paella-player:7-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.opencastproject:base:pom:7-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 7, column 11
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no 7-SNAPSHOT at Maven repository. Check out https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opencastproject/opencast-engage-paella-player